# Google Now Search as default

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean, google-now

I am developing an application for Google Now, and in my phone I have two options for voicecommand. One is Google Search and another one is Voice Search. By Default, I want to use Google Search and result should come in Google Now Voice.

Comment: Where is the actual question here? I think many of us could guess, but that's not how this site works...